# Tried to install libglib2.0-0:i386 (wine dependency), and it removed most of the apps and OS

Tags: system, wine

I was trying to install `winehq-stable` and it gave me an error that it needed some dependencies.  The first one I tried to install (`libglib2.0-0:i386`) removed most of my stuff (well over 100 packages - everything from Skype to x-windows I think)

Now when I do an `apt-get upgrade` it lists a ton of packages that "are no longer needed"

Most of the system is no longer available (e.g. Applications menu, top bar with date/time, right top icons (network, logout, messages, etc.) and the bottom toolbar also looks totally different.

I haven't rebooted it yet because I'm not sure what will happen if I do.  Is there any way to recover?

Comment: Hi Aaron, welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. I have made some changes on your post to make it look better though your choice of words DO describe your problem well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All.  I tried the suggested fix, but it didn't work.  I did find something that seemed to fix what had happened.  I used these commands to create a file with all of the packages that had been deleted.  Then I ran the file to reinstall them.

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' > restore
echo sudo apt-get install `grep Remove /var/log/apt/history.log | tail -1 | sed -e 's|Remove: ||g' -e 's|([^)]*)||g' -e 's|:[^ ]* ||g' -e 's|,||g'` >> restore
chmod +x restore 
./restore
```

I got it here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/738984/how-to-undo-apt-get-autoremove

Comment: Good to know. Please mark your answer as **answers**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to login with live CD and [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) your data in an external drive. Just in case, if this method didn’t work, you can still have your data and reinstall everything!

At the login screen, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to `tty1`.

Now, type the following commands one by one,

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt clean

sudo apt update --fix-missing

sudo apt install -f

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Finally, reboot the [system](/questions/tagged/system) using,

```
sudo reboot
```

Above instructions are grabbed from here, [https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/).